# Does Java KeyEvent work with flash games

Tags: java, flash

Is it possible to use the Java KeyEvent to sends keys to a flash game? I would like to be able to control a flash game from a Java program I have written. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. I think what you're looking for is [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). The Robot class has methods used to position the mouse cursor, click, press and release keys, and determine pixel colors at particular screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes...**

Flash can expose a function to the "outside world" using flash.external.ExternalInterface.  It has a function called addCallback, which you can use to expose said function.

At that point, it's a matter of how you intend to "reach" the swf.  Is the Java application embedded on a web page alongside the swf?  If so, Java would need to find some way to call the swf's function, most likely using JavaScript as an intermediary...

**But the real question**

But the real question is why you would want to pass along the key event into Flash from Java when you can just listen for KeyEvents in Flash natively.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the source code for the flash game. It is a flash game embedded on a webpage, and I would like to write the Java code locally on my computer to interact with the flash game.

Comment: Without access to the flash source, I don't think there's a way you can do this.  The swf has to be set up such that it exposes a function to the outside world, which it almost certainly does not in its current form.  Even if it did, you probably don't have any documentation indicating the API... and if you did have the source, you of course wouldn't need to funnel anything through Java.